# Deleting two-way trusts in Windows AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, trust-relationship

I want to remove two-way trust using `netdom trust` command on `Windows Server 2012 r2`, I am using "Run as Administrator" command prompt but still getting "Access Denied"

Here is my command

```
netdom trust testrelm.test /d:testrelm.test /remove /UserD:admin /PasswordD:Password
```

Can anyone point me what is wrong in this command or reason for "Access Denied"?

Comment: There are different levels of "admin" permissions. Try with at least Domain admin, and if that fails then Enterprise Admin? NETDOM is a rather old tool, may or may not have been update for 2012. What happens if you try removing the trust with the Domains & Trusts MMC (domain.msc)?

Comment: I can remove trust using domain.msc but want to use command line for scripting purposes. Is there any command for replacing `netdom` ?

Comment: Try the GUI once to determine if you have a perm problem, or a tool problem. If it is a problem with NETDOM, use google 'fu for "powershell domain trust"

Comment: When entering your credential, are you including the domain to ensure it's not using the local admin?
The membership of the account should be Domain/Enterprise admin

Otherwise, i don't see any problems with your syntax. Netdom should still be valid for W2k12 --->
(Remove a trust - 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc771137.aspx)

Comment: @Lex Admin is member of Domain/Enterprise user.